# Reveal animation starts before view is clipped to outline

Tags: android, android-animation, clipping

I am using a FAB button from the Android Samples([1](http://developer.android.com/samples/FloatingActionButtonBasic/project.html)).
If I understand it correctyl, the constuctor of the extended FrameLayout implementing the FAB clipps the outline to the view making it oval wheneever the view is instantiated.

```
 public FloatingActionButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr,
                            int defStyleRes) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);

    setClickable(true);

    // Set the outline provider for this view. The provider is given the outline which it can
    // then modify as needed. In this case we set the outline to be an oval fitting the height
    // and width.
    setOutlineProvider(new ViewOutlineProvider() {
        @Override
        public void getOutline(View view, Outline outline) {
            outline.setOval(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
        }
    });

    // Finally, enable clipping to the outline, using the provider we set above
    setClipToOutline(true);
}
```

I want ot reveal the button wheneever the activity is started:
I apply the reveal effect on it in the onWindowFocusChanged activity method and what happens is that the animation starts and only after it finishs the outline of the view is clipped.

```
final View fabContainer = findViewById(R.id.create_new_workout_fab);

                Animation anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(YourWorkouts.this, R.anim.reveal_fab);
                fabContainer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                Animator animator = ViewAnimationUtils.createCircularReveal(
                        fabContainer, // view to reveal
                        fabContainer.getWidth()/2, // start X coordinate of reveal
                        fabContainer.getHeight()/2, // start Y coordinate of reveal
                        0, // start radius. In most cases - 0
                        Math.max(fabContainer.getWidth(), fabContainer.getHeight()) // end radius
                );

                // Set a natural ease-in/ease-out interpolator.
                animator.setInterpolator(new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator());
                fabContainer.setClipToOutline(true);
                // Finally start the animation
                animator.start();
```

So while the reveal animation runs the view is not oval and becomes oval after the reveal animation ends.
As seen in the code I also tried to set the clipping manually before starting the animation, but it wouldnt help.

Can anybody help me out?

Answer (score 0):

I regret you can't do both things at the same time:

> Only a single non-rectangular clip can be applied on a View at any time. Views clipped by a circular reveal animation take priority over View Outline clipping.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewAnimationUtils.html

I'd try to fake it by adding a shape background drawable.